# Given A SQL Statement of the form "select a,b,c from t" and its output, can you determine the number of columns in table t?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

My professor told us to think about this question (not homework, don't worry), and I'm stumped. I know it would tell you if columns a, b and c exist in t, but if there were more columns, wouldn't it just be left out of the output?

Comment: If you select a, b, and c, then that's what the database will return to you. If the table has more columns the database won't tell you anything about it.

Comment: You're right there. It tells you that there are _at least_ 3 columns, but you won't know how many exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you could watch the system as it executed the query, and you knew the structure of the table, and there were a lot of columns, you could get a rough estimate of the length of each row by how fast the query results were produced.

Answer (score 0):

You would only know that `t` contained `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The query provides no other information.

Unfortunately, the execution plan is not going to mention the columns that are *not* in the query.  The execution plan might even be using an index on `(a, b, c)`, so performance would not be a guide.